# Modifying new user registry in Powerhsell

Tags: powershell, registry, settings

I'm writting here because this problem is making me crazy.

I'm coding a script to configure a new windows installation. Due to company rules it must be done in Powershell and no windows policies can be used.

I must create a new user and modify (via registry) a couple of configurations. No issue with those topics. Windows 10 creates the user registry file ntuser.dat once the user is logged in for the first time. My problem is that I wanted to modify the registry without ever logging in this new user. I thought I could start a job or a process in the background as the user to trigger the file generation. But it seems it's not working at all:

```
$USERNAME = $cfgData.cfg.userSettings.userName
$USERPWD = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $USERNAME -AsPlainText -Force
$PC_USER = $env:COMPUTERNAME + "\" + $USERNAME

$userCreds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $PC_USER, $USERPWD
$output = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Get-Process -Name explorer } -Credential $userCreds -Verbose
Wait-Job $output | Out-Null
```

It looks like I can edit the registry but once I log in for the first time with the user, no changes were made.

Any ideas are welcome! I thought about scheduling a task to be performed once the user logs in for the first time, but I have no idea where to start with if I choose this way of solving this problem.

Thx in advance for your time!

Ben

Comment: The logon processor does not generate the NTUSER.DAT _ab initio_; it copies it from a default user location. On my system, that's in C:\USERS\Default. Mount the NTUSER.DAT from that folder as a new registry hive, make the changes, and write it back (unmount it). When a new user logs in, the registry changes will already be made, as they will be copied from the default user.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer!. I'll give it a try and I'll post the results @JeffZeitlin

Comment: For what it's worth, if you're using a domain, it is absolutely better to use Group Policy; why does your company bar this?

Comment: No, I'm not using a domain. This should be a script to fast configure stand alone PCs (such like network settings, wallpaper, display resolution, firewall rules...) The script is fully configurable via a xml file... I don't know why the company is bannig this... My first idea was Group Policy but...

Comment: Make sure the Remote Registry service is enabled on the remote PCs and you should be able to read/write to the registry via PS. Note RR can be started remotely as long as it does not have it's Startup type set to Disabled.

Comment: @RetiredGeek - Is the Remote Registry service required to access the _local computer_ registry via PS?

Comment: No it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to keep everything posted.

I tried the solution from @Jeff Zeitlin (modify the default user NTUSER.DAT file) and it worked like a charm.
Thank you Jeff!

Ben